# How to save & open file in java ( in cmd)

Tags: java, file, class, object, save

I'm totally new to programming and this is my first project. So far I have created a 3 classes. My main class allows the users to input numbers (from kbentry class) and those numbers will be calculated (using methods in Calculating class) for the results. Now all I need is to **save the results** to a directory and then be **able to open** it later on. I'm running this in cmd. Any help is appreciated.

//Calculating class

```
public class CalculatingRocketFlightProfile { //Calculation class

//Declaring variables
public double totalImpulse ;
public double averageImpulse;
public double timeEjectionChargeFires;
public double massEmptyVehicle;
public double engineMass;
public double fuelMass; 
//Declaring variables for outputs
public double theAverageMassOfTheVehicle; //declare variables to store  results of calculations
public double theVehiclesMaximumVelocity;

//Declaring variables of outputs
public double Gravity = 9.81; //Constant variable (default)

//Constructor
public CalculatingRocketFlightProfile(double totalImpulse, double   averageImpulse, double timeEjectionChargeFires, double massEmptyVehicle,
                                  double engineMass, double fuelMass) { //Setting the parameters 

this.totalImpulse  = totalImpulse;
this.averageImpulse = averageImpulse;
this.timeEjectionChargeFires = timeEjectionChargeFires;
this.massEmptyVehicle = massEmptyVehicle;
this.engineMass = engineMass;
this.fuelMass = fuelMass;
}

//Mutators and Accessors

//Accessors
//Methods for calculations - Calculating outputs, using inputs. 

public double theAverageMassOfTheVehicle() {
    return massEmptyVehicle + ((engineMass + (engineMass - fuelMass) )  / 2 ); //Formula to calculate Average mass 
}//method

public double theVehiclesMaximumVelocity() { //Formula to calculate Maximum velocity
    return totalImpulse / theAverageMassOfTheVehicle();
}//method
}
```

//Main class

```
        public class Main { //Master class


        public static void main( String args[] ) //Standard header for main  method
        {


        kbentry input = new kbentry(); //Creates object of kbentry class

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for Total Impulse: " );   //Print message to enter 1. input
        double totalImpulse = input.totalImpulse1(); //Holds the variable  entered
        System.out.println("You have entered : " + totalImpulse); //Shows  the variable entered


        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for Average mass: " ); //Print message to enter 2. input
        double averageImpulse = input.averageImpulse2(); //Holds the variable entered
        System.out.println("You have entered : " + averageImpulse); //Shows the variable entered

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for Time ejection charge fires: " ); //Print message to enter 3. input
        double timeEjectionChargeFires = input.timeEjectionChargeFires3(); //Holds the variable entered
        System.out.println("You have entered : " + timeEjectionChargeFires); //Shows the variable entered

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for the Mass of the empty vehicle: " ); //Print message to enter 4. input
        double massEmptyVehicle = input.massEmptyVehicle4(); //Holds the variable entered
        System.out.println("You have entered : " + massEmptyVehicle); //Shows the variable entered

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for the Mass of the engine: " ); //Print message to enter 5. input
        double engineMass = input.engineMass5(); //Holds the variable entered
        System.out.println("You have entered : " + engineMass); //Shows the variable entered

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for the Mass of the fuel: " ); //Print message to enter 6. input
        double fuelMass = input.fuelMass6(); //Holds the variable entered
        System.out.println("You have entered : " + fuelMass); //Shows the variable entered




        CalculatingRocketFlightProfile calculations = new CalculatingRocketFlightProfile(totalImpulse,averageImpulse, timeEjectionChargeFires,
        massEmptyVehicle, engineMass, fuelMass); //Giving the object parameters required from constructor


            //Print out lines showing the result. 
            System.out.println("\nThe average mass of the vehicle: " +calculations.theAverageMassOfTheVehicle() /1000 + " g" +
                              "\nThe vehicles maximum velocity: " + calculations.theVehiclesMaximumVelocity() * 1000 + " m/s");

        //This is what I want to be saved and opened later. 

        }
```

//kb entry class (Methods same for all inputs e.g. averageImpulse2, timeEjectionChargeFires3....etc)
            }

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.IOException;


 public class kbentry{ //Class name

 double totalImpulse1(){ //Method for 1. input

 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));   //Creates BufferedReader object for System.in

//Total Impulse entry
String strTotalImpulse = null;  // These must be initialised
double    intTotalImpulse = 0; //Setting it double

try {
  strTotalImpulse = in.readLine(); //Reads string value from the keyboard
} 
catch (IOException ioe) {  // ignore exception

   }

try {
  intTotalImpulse = Double.parseDouble(strTotalImpulse);  // convert it to double
} 
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
System.out.println("Error! Please enter a number!" + nfe.toString());  //Error message if its not a double

System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for Total Impulse: "); //again ask for input again
return totalImpulse1(); //Returns value, so it can be re-entered
}

return intTotalImpulse; //return value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself when I was making a similar program. You're going to want to use a FileWriter, similar to the code below, I don't know where you want this, but here is how to write (and create) a file to an (existing) directory:

```
final File file = new File("C:\\path\\to\\dir");
file.createNewFile();
FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
fileOut.write("Here is where you write to the file";
/*you can write to the file again with out erasing the contents by
* using the .append() method*/ 
fileOut.close();
```

Also, are you using eclipse, or are you literally coding in cmd. If so, you should probs get eclipse. You will also want to import the File (java.io) and FileWriter classes in your main.

You should put this under this snippet of code:

```
//Print out lines showing the result. 
        System.out.println("\nThe average mass of the vehicle: " +calculations.theAverageMassOfTheVehicle() /1000 + " g" +
                          "\nThe vehicles maximum velocity: " + calculations.theVehiclesMaximumVelocity() * 1000 + " m/s");

    //This is what I want to be saved and opened later.
```

Like this:

```
//Print out lines showing the result. 
        System.out.println("\nThe average mass of the vehicle: " +calculations.theAverageMassOfTheVehicle() /1000 + " g" +
                          "\nThe vehicles maximum velocity: " + calculations.theVehiclesMaximumVelocity() * 1000 + " m/s");
String theAverageMass = "The average mass of the vehicle: " +calculations.theAverageMassOfTheVehicle() /1000 + " g";
String theMaxVelocity = "\nThe vehicles maximum velocity: " + calculations.theVehiclesMaximumVelocity() * 1000 + " m/s"
    //This is what I want to be saved and opened later. 

final File file = new File("C:\\path\\to\\dir\\yourSaveFile.txt");
file.createNewFile();
FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
fileOut.write(theAverageMass+theMaxVelocity);
/*you can write to the file again with out erasing the contents by
* using the .append() method*/ 
fileOut.close();
```

Your main class should be (with proper imports):

```
public class Main { //Master class


    public static void main( String args[] ) //Standard header for main  method
    {


    kbentry input = new kbentry(); //Creates object of kbentry class

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for Total Impulse: " );   //Print message to enter 1. input
    double totalImpulse = input.totalImpulse1(); //Holds the variable  entered
    System.out.println("You have entered : " + totalImpulse); //Shows  the variable entered


    System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for Average mass: " ); //Print message to enter 2. input
    double averageImpulse = input.averageImpulse2(); //Holds the variable entered
    System.out.println("You have entered : " + averageImpulse); //Shows the variable entered

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for Time ejection charge fires: " ); //Print message to enter 3. input
    double timeEjectionChargeFires = input.timeEjectionChargeFires3(); //Holds the variable entered
    System.out.println("You have entered : " + timeEjectionChargeFires); //Shows the variable entered

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for the Mass of the empty vehicle: " ); //Print message to enter 4. input
    double massEmptyVehicle = input.massEmptyVehicle4(); //Holds the variable entered
    System.out.println("You have entered : " + massEmptyVehicle); //Shows the variable entered

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for the Mass of the engine: " ); //Print message to enter 5. input
    double engineMass = input.engineMass5(); //Holds the variable entered
    System.out.println("You have entered : " + engineMass); //Shows the variable entered

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for the Mass of the fuel: " ); //Print message to enter 6. input
    double fuelMass = input.fuelMass6(); //Holds the variable entered
    System.out.println("You have entered : " + fuelMass); //Shows the variable entered




    CalculatingRocketFlightProfile calculations = new CalculatingRocketFlightProfile(totalImpulse,averageImpulse, timeEjectionChargeFires,
    massEmptyVehicle, engineMass, fuelMass); //Giving the object parameters required from constructor


        //Print out lines showing the result. 
        System.out.println("\nThe average mass of the vehicle: " +calculations.theAverageMassOfTheVehicle() /1000 + " g" +
                          "\nThe vehicles maximum velocity: " + calculations.theVehiclesMaximumVelocity() * 1000 + " m/s");
        String theAverageMass = "The average mass of the vehicle: " +calculations.theAverageMassOfTheVehicle() /1000 + " g";
        String theMaxVelocity = "\nThe vehicles maximum velocity: " + calculations.theVehiclesMaximumVelocity() * 1000 + " m/s";
            //This is what I want to be saved and opened later. 

        final File file = new File("C:\\path\\to\\dir\\yourSaveFile.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        fileOut.write(theAverageMass+theMaxVelocity);
        /*you can write to the file again with out erasing the contents by
        * using the .append() method*/ 
        fileOut.close();


    }
```

}

Comment: I'm writing the code using Notepad++, and compile it in CMD. Thanks for the code I'll give it a try and let you know. Do I use this within my main class or in a separate one?

Comment: I'm not too sure what to do with this code, could you show where I should include it?

Comment: sure! Just give me a minute to figure it out. I haven't fully read your code.

Comment: sorry, I'm not done the answer and have to go, I'll post it in about an hour.

Comment: Do I include the final Final final = new File (etc...) lines in or outside the main?

Comment: Right under the the `System.out.print()` statement, just like I said.

Comment: In the main, to answer your question.

Comment: I will edit my answer again to show what your full main class should look like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73352/discussion-between-yrekundmaets-and-scott-allen).

Comment: Always willing to help! If you thought my answer did it, you could click the check box next to my answer.